# Getting current culture day names in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Is it possible to get the `CurrentCulture`'s weekdays from `DateTimeFormatInfo`, but returning **Monday** as first day of the week instead of **Sunday**.  And, if the current culture isn't English (i.e. the ISO code isn't "en") then leave it as default.

By default `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames` returns:

```
[0]: "Sunday"
[1]: "Monday"
[2]: "Tuesday"
[3]: "Wednesday"
[4]: "Thursday"
[5]: "Friday"
[6]: "Saturday"
```

But I need:

```
[0]: "Monday"
[1]: "Tuesday"
[2]: "Wednesday"
[3]: "Thursday"
[4]: "Friday"
[5]: "Saturday" 
[6]: "Sunday"
```

Comment: This question is a bit confusing for the following reason: You want to return English day names starting on Monday, but you want to retain the default ordering for any other culture - so, you do not actually want to know which string represents which day in cultures that are not English?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [custom cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx) to create a new culture based off an existing one. To be honest, though, I'd say that's probably a bit heavy-handed. The "simplest" solution may just be something like:

```
public string[] GetDayNames()
{
    if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.StartsWith("en-"))
    {
        return new [] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
    }
    else
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I think this is probably easiest. I ended up using `if (CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en")` to check for English.

Answer (score 7):

You can Clone the current culture which gets a writable copy of the CultureInfo object. Then you can set the DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek to Monday.

```
CultureInfo current = CultureInfo.Current;
CultureInfo clone = (CultureInfo)current.Clone();

clone.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
```

The above `clone` will now treat Monday as the first day of the week.

**EDIT**

After re-reading your question I don't think this will do what you're expecting. The DayNames will still return in the same order regardless of the `FirstDayOfWeek` setting.

But I'll leave this answer up as community wiki in case someone comes across this question in the future.

Comment: Wow, I never knew it was that easy!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried this and was disappointed to still get the days back in the same order.  Good idea though.

Answer (score 5):

I am posting this as a separate answer as it really has nothing to do with my other answer (which may be useful to someone else in the future in another context.)

As an alternative to codeka's solution, you can also do something like this (which would avoid having to hard code the en-us day names.)

```
string[] dayNamesNormal = culture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
string[] dayNamesShifted = Shift(dayNamesNormal, (int)DayOfWeek.Monday);

// you probably wanna add some error checking here.
// this method shifts array left by a specified number
// of positions, wrapping the shifted elements back to
// end of the array
private static T[] Shift<T>(T[] array, int positions) {
    T[] copy = new T[array.Length];
    Array.Copy(array, 0, copy, array.Length-positions, positions);
    Array.Copy(array, positions, copy, 0, array.Length-positions);
    return copy;
}
```

I meant to post this sooner but I am fighting a dying external hard drive...

Comment: Nice solution, I like the Shift method, a handy one to keep in the library.

Answer (score 5):

One more idea, inspired by Josh's answer, using a Queue instead of shifting the array.

```
var days = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en")
{
    var q = new Queue<string>(days);
    q.Enqueue(q.Dequeue());
    days = q.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Clever! It sure is easier on the eyes than the direct array manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

[DatetimeFormatInfo.GetDayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getdayname%28VS.71%29.aspx) obviously, with a foreach on each DayOfWeek in the order you want. :) No hack, simple and effective

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting day names based on dates, it doesn't matter what day the week starts on; DateTimeFormat.DayNames identifies Sunday as 0, as does DateTime, no matter if weeks start on Thursday or what have you. :)

To get day name in English from a date:

```
string GetDayName(DateTime dt)
{
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int)dt.DayOfWeek];
}
```

If for some reason you absolutely want to deal with the (magic value!) ints that underpin the DayOfWeek enumeration, just shift the index and take the modulus, hence mapping 0 => 6, 1 => 0, and so on:

```
string GetDayName(int dayIndex)
{
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(dayIndex + 6) % 7]; 
}
```

Comment: "DateTimeFormat.DayNames identifies Sunday as 0" - this statement appears to be wrong. The [docs on `DayNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.daynames) state: "The first element (the element at index zero) represents the first day of the week in the calendar defined by the Calendar property."

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution:

```
var dayNames = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames.ToList();

if (Culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    dayNames.Add(dayNames[0]);
    dayNames.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since only one day is being moved, I solved this problem like this:

```
'the list is from Sunday to Saturday
'we need Monday to Sunday
'so add a Sunday on the end and then remove the first position
dayNames.AddRange(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.DayNames)
dayNames.Add(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
dayNames.RemoveAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work nice.

```
    public static List<String> Days
    {
        var abbDayNames = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;

        var days = new string[7];
        var firstDayOfWeek = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday;
        for (int i = 6; i>= 0; i--)
        {
            days[i] = abbDayNames[(firstDayOfWeek + i) % 7];
        }

        return new List<string>(days);
    }
```