# How to sort my Days List, so I can have my monday as my first Item instead of Sunday?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, xamarin

I have a String List with my Days of the Week, and it starts with Sunday as first item [0], how can I change the order so I have Monday as my first item of my list?

Here is my Days List:

```
public static List<String> Days
{
    get
    {
        return new List<string>(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting current culture day names in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901220/getting-current-culture-day-names-in-net)

Comment: Days normally are Sunday = 0 ... Saturday = 6.  So if you use the MOD function you can do ((int)DayOfWeek - 1) % 7.  DayOfWeek is an enumeration that you can cast to an integer (0 to 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this runs perfectly. It is maybe not very nice code but it do what it should do.

```
    public static List<String> Days
    {
        var abbDayNames = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;

        var days = new string[7];
        var firstDayOfWeek = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday;
        for (int i = 6; i>= 0; i--)
        {
            days[i] = abbDayNames[(firstDayOfWeek + i) % 7];
        }

        return new List<string>(days);
    }
```

**EDIT:** I edited a code little bit so it is not so stupid, and doing unnecessary things. But I believe it can be much better.