# how to dynamically create array of a week days in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Instead of specifying
"string[] week_Days = {"Monday", "Tuesday"...};"

How to dynamically set days as array?

I tried solving it, but couldn't get starting day as "Sunday" -

```
DateTime days = DateTime.Now;  
string[] weekDays = new string[7];  
for (int i = 0; i < weekDays.Length; i++)  
  {  
    weekDays[i] = string.Format("{0:dddd}", days.AddDays(i));  
    Console.WriteLine(weekDays[i]);     
    days = DateTime.Now;  
  }
```

Output -

```
Wednesday  
Thursday  
Friday  
Saturday  
Sunday  
Monday  
Tuesday
```

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames` ?

Comment: What were the full results of this code?

Comment: This does not work bc you are starting with today's DateTime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting current culture day names in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901220/getting-current-culture-day-names-in-net)

Comment: No there is no automatic way to do it. Yes use the DayOfWeek enum. No there is no automatic way to start with Monday. Yes simply `new[]{ DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday,` etc etc etc

Comment: @NaveenKumar Strange solution you picked there - your comment at a different answer also applies there `What if i want to set starting day as "Monday"?` - with this solution you also can't specify `Monday` to start - the last entry in the array will just simply out put `7` if you would say `DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.Monday;`

Comment: This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901479/2598770 - of the possbile duplicate is way better and doesn't lack the globalization - so you are getting translated weekdays depending on your culture and not just the english names. - instead of the hardcoded `(int)DayOfWeek.Monday` in that example you could just say `(int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2) enum:

```
string[] weekdays = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek));
```

**EDIT:** If you need to change the start day of the week:

```
private static string[] GetWeekdays(DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
{
    string[] weekdays = new string[7];
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    while (dateTime.DayOfWeek != firstDayOfWeek)
    {
        // Find the next date with start day of week
        dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        // Get day of week of current day, add 1 day, iterate 7 times.
        weekdays[i] = dateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1);
    }
    return weekdays;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works, But what if i want to set starting day as "Monday"?

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

static void Main()
{
    string[] weekDays = new CultureInfo("en-us").DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(weekDays[i % 7]);
}
```

Comment: why do you use `weekDays[i % 7]` instead of `i`?

Comment: To avoid the exception and the days of the week was Monday through Sunday. In the array, the first element is Sunday.

Comment: ah i get it.. it returns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0

Comment: weekDays[1]  => "Monday" weekDays[0] => "Sunday"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this LINQ query. The only challenge is to get the correct order:

```
DayOfWeek firstWeekDay = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek;
string[] weekDays = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>()
   .OrderBy(dow => dow < firstWeekDay ? 7-(int)dow : dow-firstWeekDay)
   .Select(dow => dow.ToString())
   .ToArray();
```

Maybe someone has a more elegant way than this `OrderBy`.

Comment: Why not just Enum.GetNames?

Comment: @Adrian: because OP wants the correct order and not starting with Sunday. I assume that the correct order is defined through `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek` which is `Monday` for me.

Comment: Well, it depends on the culture then. And some cultures start with sunday..

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] week_Days = new string[7];  
DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.Sunday;  
for (int i = 0; i < week_Days.Length; i++)  
 {  
    week_Days[i] = day.ToString();  
    Console.WriteLine(week_Days[i]);  
    day++;  
 }
```

Instead of assigning DateTime property, Use DayOfWeek. it solves the issue with ease.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Strange solution you picked there - your comment at a different answer also applies here `What if i want to set starting day as "Monday"?` - with this solution you also can't specify `Monday` to start - the last entry in the array will just simply out put `7` if you would say `DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.Monday;`

Comment: @Rand Random Yeah Right, just now noticed it. When DayOfWeek goes out of bound, it returns numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because `DateTime.Now` isn't always on a sunday:

```
DateTime days = DateTime.Now;
```

Better use the existing `DayOfWeek` enum:

```
 string[] weekdays = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek));
```

Comment: What if i want to set starting day as "Monday"?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in this way too. Until you get "Monday", add days to the DateTime.Now.

```
int j = 0;
string[] weekDays = new string[7];
DateTime days = DateTime.Now;

while (weekDays[0] != "Sunday")
{ 
    days = days.AddDays(j++);
    weekDays[0] = string.Format("{0:dddd}", days);
    if (weekDays[0] != "Sunday")
       days = DateTime.Now;  
}

for (int i = 0; i < weekDays.Length; i++)
{
    weekDays[i] = string.Format("{0:dddd}", days.AddDays(i));
    Console.WriteLine(weekDays[i]);   
}
```

Comment: There's a one-line solution for this. The complexity... the complexity...